# IDLE Shell error in "Automate the boring stuff" with python, lesson 24

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm on lesson 24 in "Automate the Boring stuff". Overall it's been great and I've been able to figure out the obstacles. However, he's asking us to run several lines of code in the Shell program; when he does it, it runs and makes sense. When I do it, gives an error message saying it's running several lines. When I've searched for questions like mine, I see people saying to download the Shell that I'm already using.

Is this an outdated issue with the course? I really want to finish it but am worried this will be used in future lessons and will make the program less accessible.

Thank you for any thoughts; I really appreciate your patience and goodwill.

[image: screenshotofshellandcoursevideo]

Comment: You are missing a `\ ` in your regex (the first `d` should be `\d`)